# Will Ubuntu make android programming eaisier on netbook?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, ubuntu

I have Windows 7 starter on my netbook (Dual core, 1GB of RAM). If i switch to Ubuntu will it make eclipse more responsive? I can program on windows but it is a little slow and the emulator doesn't work.

Comment: Probably more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com... To answer your question, I don't think you'll be able to run the emulator even on Ubuntu, it and eclipse are an absolute resource hogs. Only one way to find out though, try installing Ubuntu and see how you go.

Comment: Mike - How long do you wait for the emulator to start?  Its first run took like 10 minutes for me.  Apparently it has to do a -ton- of setup the first time.  After that it's only like 1 minute each time I use it.  (This is on a 2.2 GHz dual-core laptop with 4GB of RAM, on Ubuntu)

Comment: I did try installing Ubuntu and I had a hard time figuring it out and wasn't sure how to install the software. I left the emulator on for 15 minutes then I closed it because it only displayed the boot logo.

Comment: With 1G RAM you're pretty much screwed, come on: Eclipse + emulator + Windows on a desktop with 1G RAM is highly questionable, and it has actual IO speed. Get another gig, and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it.  The OS is not the issue, the tools are.  Only having 1GB of RAM, that's going to be fully eaten up once everything is running, so you'll be paging to disk, and on a Netbook that disk is probably not the speediest.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better on Linux as opposed to Windows. less bloat to work around and many more options

Answer (score 1):

Linux won’t need special USB drivers to communicate with Android devices. Also integrated package management makes it easier to install prerequisites like OpenJDK, Eclipse, Ant and Git.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I used to have a horrible laptop that was extremely slow on windows. Installed Ubuntu, and it was **VERY** fast! Try it out, you can just put the disk in and try it out before installing it.